# How to insert values into db after some prechecks

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert some values into the db, but before inserting them into I want to make sure that there is no duplicate entry for same user against same `offername` and for `current date`

I am using this query and is working fine for `userid` and `date`

```
//checking for existing values
$sql11=$Db1->query("SELECT COUNT(userid) AS total FROM TABLE where userid='$userid' and date BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()");
        $temp=$Db1->fetch_array($sql11);
         $thismemberinfo['count']=$temp[total]; 
    //   
       if ($thismemberinfo['count'] >= 1 ) 
        {  WARN HERE  for duplicate entry}
        else 
        { INSERT TO DB }
```

I want to include `offername` into checking as well 
something like that

```
SELECT COUNT(userid) AS total FROM TABLE where userid='$userid' and  offername= '$offername'  date BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()
```

Kindly Suggest a work around for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note:**
>
> You should not use table name as *`TABLE`* and column name *`date`* since these two words were **reserved word** in query. Use another name.
>
> In order to make your query more simpler, just check both column (user_id & date) before add.

See my codes on how I would do.

```
//checking for existing values
$sql11=$Db1->query("SELECT COUNT(userid) AS total FROM TABLE where userid='$userid' AND offername= '$offername' AND  date BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()");
$temp = $Db1->fetch_array($sql11);
$thismemberinfo['count']=$temp['total'];  
if ($thismemberinfo['count'] >= 1) {
    // Just do nothing 
} else {
    //INSERT TO DB 
    //Current date
    $current_date = date('Y-m-d');

    $Db1->query("INSERT INTO TABLE (userid,offername,date) VALUES ('$user_id','$offername','$current_date')");
    //Table should be replace with suitable name since TABLE is a reserved word in query
}
```

Comment: `$temp[total]` shouldn't be like this until or unless you have declared `total` as `CONSTANT`, and I don't think so that it's `const` here, so it should be `$temp['total']`.

Comment: sql11=$Db1->query("SELECT COUNT(userid) AS total FROM TABLE where userid='$userid' and  offername= '$offername'  date BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW() ..... As per your resonse. is this query correct ... please recheck it ... I am only confused between many number of "AND" into the query.